# Find, grep and then create table

Tags: bash, grep, find, columns, exec

I am trying to find all `*.md` at `${PWD}`, then grep for lines beginning with `title:` and print it along with the absolute filepath `-H` and the line number of the pattern match `-n`, then I try to output the result in a table with separator `-s` as `:`

```
find ${PWD} -type f -name "*.md" -exec bash -c 'i="$1"; grep -HnE "^title:" $1; | column -t -s :;' _ {} \;
```

This is working till grep but I am unable to create a table.

Also, from the correction suggested by @steeldriver, the exec seems to be happening on each `find` result one by one, thereby table is not being created?

---

Sample Output

```
/Admin/Specification/Specification.md    2  title   Specification
/Admin/GraphicCard/index.md              2  title   "GraphicCard"
```

Comment: What's the purpose in life of that underscore before `{}`?  And what actually happens?  Sample output would go a long way...

Comment: `_` is for `$0`

Comment: Try removing the `;` between the grep command and the pipe ...

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! If I redirect the results as `find ${PWD} -type f -name "*.md" -exec bash -c 'i="$1"; grep -HnE "^title:" $1 | column -t -s : ' _ {}\; > FILE` The columns are not preserved anymore. Could you suggest why?

Comment: @steeldriver I thought that `-exec` would execute on all finds together. This result suggest that the column is operating on individual lines! Defeating the purpose here.

Comment: You can put the `column` command outside (in which case you don't need the extra shell) i.e. `find ${PWD} -type f -name "*.md" -exec grep -HnE "^title:" {} \; | column -t -s:`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! But is `exec` executes here on find results one by one? Is it possible to do exec once after finding all files? This could quicken the result.

Comment: If your `find` supports it, you can use `{} +` in place of `{} \;`

Comment: @steeldriver `_ {} +;` doesn't work while using subshell with exec, otherwise, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be overthinking things.  Rather than trying to tabulate the results of `grep`, why not let `awk`, a prolific table-maker, make the table for you?

```
find . -type f -name \*.md -print0 | xargs -0 awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } /^title:/ { print FILENAME, FNR, $0 }'
```

`find` will locate all the `md` files you're interested in, and pass them all as arguments to `awk` by way of `xargs`.  We then just have `awk` spit out, on lines that match your criterium, the name of the file (which `find` will have passed with the full relative path), the record number in the file (i. e. the line number), and the line as seen in the file; all separated by tabs as defined in `OFS`, the Output Field Separator.

If you want to be a little more exact with the alignment of your output, you could instead do something like:

```
/^title:/ { printf( "%35s %4d %s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0 ) }
```

Also, if you don't want to `find | xargs awk` but would rather `find -exec`, this also works:

```
find . -name \*.md -type f -exec awk '/expiry/ { printf( "%30s %4d %s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0 ) }' "{}" +
```

Comment: How about `-exec` with  `+;`? Is it better if I am not concerned with portability?

Comment: That will also work just fine, yes.  I have added that invocation to the answer.